# The difference between Type I strings and Type II strings

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry, duality

I understand Type II strings but i do not understand the difference between [Type I](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_I_string_theory) and [Type II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_II_string_theory) strings. Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: What about the explanations in the source where you read about them is unclear to you? Can you be more specific *what* you don't understand?

Comment: @ACuriousMind i have read the wikipedia article on these strings but i simply cant find the difference

Comment: Your statement of "I understand type II strings" is based on having read the rather sparse Wikipedia article? That'd call for a very different kind of answer than to someone actually trying to learn string theory from a textbook or articles.

Comment: @ACuriousMind im just asking for someone to explain it to me, if you dont want to then thats fine

Comment: The main difference is in existence of open strings in Type I.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type II superstring theory starts from the assumption that small perturbations of the vacuum state result only in orientable closed[*] strings.

By contrast, Type I superstring theory starts from the assumption that perturbations near the vacuum state can be either open or closed strings, but both must be non-orientable.

Another difference is that while Type II theories have two 10-dimensional supersymmetry generators, Type I theories have only one.  This difference is a consequence of the non-orientability of Type I strings.  Assuming the strings are non-orientable means forcing the positive and negative chiral components of the worldsheet spinors to be dependent on each other.  They are both determined by the same set of modes, not two different sets of modes as in Type II.

For Type I superstring theory, anomaly cancellation requires the gauge group to be SO(32).

[*] Type II does include open strings.  However, they don't show up in the vacuum perturbation theory--they are only there in connection with non-perturbative effects (D-branes).